# Quill JS white-spaces are not preserved

Tags: javascript, html, css, quill

I've added quill js editor to my website. When I testing it by alerting the content, any text that we inserted after white space is emitted.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="postCommentEditor" class="postCommentEditor ql-align-right ql-direction-rtl"></div>
```

JS:

```
const quillEditor = new Quill('#postCommentEditor', {
    modules: {
        toolbar: true,
    },
    theme: 'snow',
});

quillEditor.format('direction', 'rtl');
quillEditor.format('align', 'right');
```

CSS:

```
.postCommentEditor {
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

I tried to alert the input in the editor:

```
let $contentOBJ = $(quillEditor.root).children()[0].innerHTML;
alert($contentOBJ);
```

So when I type:

```
aaaa
test
```

I only get in the alert `aaaa`..

Answer (score 2):

It happens because Quill renders HTML and in your case it is something like

```
<p>aaaa</p>
<p>test</p>
```

So when you are retrieving content like this:
`let $contentOBJ = $(quillEditor.root).children()[0].innerHTML;`
You will obviously get only content of the first child, which is `aaaa`

To get all text use `let $contentOBJ = $(quillEditor.root).innerHTML;` or `quillEditor.getText()`